# plotnine geom_smooth formula exp not defined

Tags: python, python-ggplot, plotnine

I'm using

```
+ geom_smooth(method="lm", formula= ("y ~ exp(x)"))
```

in plotnine, but I got the following error:

```
NameError: name 'exp' is not defined
```

I haven't used ggplot in R, but I saw this works in R. How do I make this work in python?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `"y ~ np.exp(x)"` ? With `import numpy as np`, if it isn't already in your code. I haven't used plotnine, but I'm going by the documentation that suggests `np.sin(col1)` is a valid expression: https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/glossary.html